# Google Marketplace App can only be accessed by giving Domain Admin giving access a user at a time. Require automatic access to all domain users

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

My scenario is as follows:

We built a grade school application that was approved for the Google Marketplace. When the school Google domain administrator installed the application, he had no problems. Going to the application settings he did not expect to see the user the access panel. The application is requiring the domain admin to give access to the school application one user at a time. For a domain with over 2,000 users, giving access to each, one at a time, can become a big problem. I have seen many Google Marketplace Apps where the admin does not have to give access to each domain user, basically because the app is already accessible to all domain users.

What API (such as DIRECTORY API) did we have to include in our application? Or did we miss anything in the Application Manifest to overcome this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited your post to make your ask more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you [specify the same scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing) in the APIs Console as you request in your app, users will not be prompted.